Cant download netfilterqueue, any ideas on how to fix? Alternative?
Tried Downloading Netfilterqueue with all the python 3 versions that microsoft store has from 3.7 - 3.12 and it's not working. How can I fix the download "pyproject.toml" error? What other alternative pytho modules similar to netfilterqueue are there?
P.S. I have a windows 11 Pro host
C:\Users\theon>pip install netfilterqueue
Collecting netfilterqueue
  Using cached NetfilterQueue-1.1.0.tar.gz (90 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: netfilterqueue
  Building wheel for netfilterqueue (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for netfilterqueue (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\netfilterqueue
      copying netfilterqueue\_version.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\netfilterqueue
      copying netfilterqueue\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\netfilterqueue
      running egg_info
      writing NetfilterQueue.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to NetfilterQueue.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing top-level names to NetfilterQueue.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'NetfilterQueue.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'NetfilterQueue.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying netfilterqueue\_impl.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\netfilterqueue
      copying netfilterqueue\_impl.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\netfilterqueue
      copying netfilterqueue\_impl.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\netfilterqueue
      copying netfilterqueue\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-38\netfilterqueue
      running build_ext
      building 'netfilterqueue._impl' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\netfilterqueue
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\include" "-IC:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.40.33807\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /Tcnetfilterqueue/_impl.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\netfilterqueue/_impl.obj
      _impl.c
      netfilterqueue/_impl.c(1239): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.40.33807\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for netfilterqueue
Failed to build netfilterqueue
ERROR: Could not build wheels for netfilterqueue, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`


netfilter is linux kernel feature, it will not work on windows host unless you use something like WSL

Take a look at the Pypi page:

This, plus your error message Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory suggest, that this module is not compatible with windows.
You can try installing and using this module in WSL

thanks man, i am a begginer in programming. Need to take a look more on the documentations of modules etc..
